# SELinux context documentation

Tags: linux, centos7, selinux

I am trying to get my head around SELinux but one question keeps popping-up in my head: CONTEXT.

When I'm writing custom rules and modules (on CentOS 7), I end up just taking contexts out of the air - this is my understanding so far:

- `seinfo -t -x` lists all contexts along with their attributes.
- `sesearch` displays all present rules, so if I were interested in what httpd_t can currently access I would use something like `sesearch -A -s httpd_t`.
- `semanage fcontext -l` to list all present rules.
- `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts` a few files here such as customizable_types, so I end up using those.

However I still am just picking contexts out of the air with no real information about what context should be used.

I have been searching everywhere for context descriptions, but there seem to be none available - apache alone has:

> httpd_php_tmp_t
>      httpd_var_lib_t
>      httpd_var_run_t
>      httpd_user_htaccess_t
>      httpd_sys_content_t
>      httpd_sys_htaccess_t
>      httpd_user_script_exec_t
>      httpd_rotatelogs_t
>      httpd_suexec_tmp_t
>      httpd_unconfined_script_exec_t
>      httpd_user_ra_content_t
>      httpd_user_rw_content_t
>      httpd_suexec_t
>      httpd_config_t
>      httpd_bool_t
>      httpd_php_t
>      httpd_tmp_t
>      httpd_user_script_t
>      httpd_helper_exec_t
>      httpd_squirrelmail_t
>      httpd_php_exec_t
>      httpd_sys_ra_content_t
>      httpd_sys_rw_content_t
>      httpd_modules_t
>      httpd_sys_script_t
>      httpd_user_content_t
>      httpd_suexec_exec_t
>      httpd_unit_file_t
>      httpd_unconfined_script_t
>      httpd_initrc_exec_t
>      httpd_t
>      httpd_rotatelogs_exec_t
>      httpd_passwd_t
>      httpd_helper_t
>      httpd_keytab_t
>      httpd_exec_t
>      httpd_lock_t
>      httpd_log_t
>      httpd_cache_t
>      httpd_tmpfs_t
>      httpd_sys_script_exec_t
>      httpd_passwd_exec_t

Some of the names of the contexts are self-explanatory, however surely there is some documentation somewhere for this?

Answer (score 0):

SELinux contexts are documented in policy module man pages. Apache SELinux policy documentation is in *httpd_selinux* man page.

If you have `selinux-policy-devel` installed, you can generate the man pages by running:

```
sepolicy manpage -a -p /usr/local/man/man8
mandb
```

(also asked on [U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418651/239817))